# Laravel, Problemas al actualizar un registro. Guarda cualquier campo que le modifique, pero hay un campo q no lo modifica

Tags: laravel, eloquent, update

Este es el código del controller, cualquier campo lo actualiza, menos el señalado. Es un FK de la tabla Departamentos. Lo actualizo por BD y todo bien, pero con el programa me dice q actualizo pero no ese campo.
[image]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 2):

El error era que tenia definido en Fillable el nombre del campo anterior que era de gerencia_id y lo cambie por departamento_id

```
protected $fillable = [
        'rut',
        'apellidopaterno',
        'apellidomaterno',
        'nombre',
        'direccion',
        'sexo',
        'fechanacimiento',
        'fechaingreso',
        'fonohabitacion',
        'celular',
        'cargo_id',
        **'departamento_id',** //aqui estaba el campo gerencia_id
        'role',
        'email',
        'password',
        'status'
    ];
```